# How to deploy remixjs standalone?

Tags: javascript

I was using Nextjs before, and recently I am going to migrate the project to remixjs.

In nextjs, building the minimum production version can be done by setting:

```
const nextConfig = {
  //...
  output: "standalone",
  //...
};
```

It can package the used node_modules package together without re-npm install.

Is there an equivalent way in remixjs? Or through what operation can achieve standalone?